# Can I ask for feedback on an idea for a standard?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I'm looking to come up with a **standard for how to implement a system that will automatically update software**. As such, there is no actual programming per se, but I still want to make sure my standard is robust before moving on to the stage where I build a proof-of-concept prototype.

I have a good outline of the idea, which is what I would want to be critiqued, but no actual code as of yet.

**Can I ask for a review of my idea for a standard here?** If so, what do I use as tags (I'm thinking [architecture], [design], andor [networking])? If not, where would be the best place to go for this ([I was told that this SE would at least fit better than Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4973/can-i-ask-for-feedback-on-an-idea-for-a-standard))?

For reference, the idea which I would be posing is [The BARC on GitHub](https://github.com/BlueHuskyStudios/The-BARC/blob/Refine/Refine.txt).

Comment: see also: [Green fields, blue skys, and the white board - what is too broad?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/green-fields-blue-skys-and-the-white-board-what-is-too-broad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of question is absolutely fine, provided you make it specific enough to be answerable. For example:

> I'm thinking of using a RESTful API for a gambling site I'm working
>   on. Is this a good idea?

This would too broad.

> I'm having trouble deciding between REST and SOAP for a gambling site
>   I'm working on. We need to deliver a viable product quickly, so the simplicity
>   of REST is appealing, but in the long run we would definitely like
>   features that are hard to achieve without SOAP and I'm afraid we might
>   be shooting ourselves in the foot by jumping on the "quick and dirty" solution now.
>   How hard is it to migrate to SOAP later? Is this a real problem or am I just being paranoid?

This, on the other hand, is probably answerable by anyone with significant experience working on REST and SOAP web APIs.

A design question about the relative pros/cons of specific approaches you're interested in--or one that focuses on a specific problem you're having--is much more likely to be well-received on this site than a simple "here's my design, does it look good?" poll.

Comment: Thanks for a great example! I'll use it to improve my question!